# telnet connect to bluestacks not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, call

I'm trying to make call for testing purposes in my bluestacks android emulator.
I tired

```
telnet localhost 5555
```

but my cmd goes blank after this.

[Command prompt after telnet command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYHb.png)

Why is it showing blank?

Is there any other way to call to an android emulator.

Edit:
I need to process incoming call in my android application, so I need to generate a fake call.
The application I'm trying to build also require root(Super User) access.
I tried using Android Studio AVD, it can make incoming calls using telnet or ddms but what I want to do requires root permission.
I tried genymotion but the free version doesn't allow calling feature.

So I'm stuck with Bluestacks, it rooted by default & I just need way to generate an actual incoming call just like

```
gsm call 123456789
```

Comment: port 5555 is generally a debugger port. I personally don't know bluestacks, but I'm guessing that you're connecting to the debugger process. Manually, you will probably not find anything.
You can use a debugger (like eclipse) to connect and set breakpoints in your code.